# What does this mean? "Create a histogram for each single numeric corresponding to different categorical variable"

Tags: r, data-visualization

So I am working on the esoph dataset that is provided by default in RStudio. The data set explores correlations between age, smoking, drinking and oesophageal cancer.

One of the questions we have to ask ourselves as part of our statistics lecture is the question mentioned above.

However, in R, the histogram function is called using numerical variables as a parameter not categorical... I'm only able to plot the histograms for numerical variables such as:

- Ncontrols
- Ncases

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the question is not put well but will still offer a possible solution.

But first you should not assume that everyone here knows these data. At least we should present a `str`:

```
> str(esoph)
'data.frame':   88 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ agegp    : Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "25-34"<"35-44"<..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ alcgp    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "0-39g/day"<"40-79"<..: 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
 $ tobgp    : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "0-9g/day"<"10-19"<..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
 $ ncases   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ncontrols: num  40 10 6 5 27 7 4 7 2 1 ...
```

So there are two numeric variables that can be displayed in a histogram. Now what exactly is meant by "corresponding to categorical variable"?

R offers a simple syntax for boxplots and I am tempted to assume, that the question meant boxplot instead of histogram:

```
boxplot(esoph$ncases ~ esoph$agegp)
```

[image]

Now with histograms it is far more complicated to arrange that. You can of course draw a histogram at a time in a for loop. Something like

```
for(group in levels(esoph$agegp))
  hist(esoph$ncases[esoph$agegp==group], main=paste("Agegp = ", group),
       xlim=c(0, 18))
```

This will draw a histogramm of a numerical for each level of a categorical variable. And you could combine those in a single graphic like

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for(group in levels(esoph$agegp))
  hist(esoph$ncases[esoph$agegp==group], main=paste("Agegp = ", group),
       xlim=c(0, 18))
```

[image]

Which is as close to understanding the question as I get.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(esoph)

df = esoph

p = ggplot(df_m)
p = p + geom_bar(aes(x=agegp))
print(p)
```

[image]